# Adding links to this PHP statement

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, plugins, hyperlink

Here is a PHP statement that basically sets off a javascript image slider.  Only problem is I can't figure out how to get each individual image to a link to a different page.  Any tips or suggestions?  I appreciate it!

```
<?php jsbrotate('height=316&width=924&imgdisp=4&imgfade=2&images=/wp-content/uploads/image_1_linked.png|/wp-content/uploads/image_2.png|/wp-content/uploads/image_3.png|/wp-content/uploads/image_4.png|/wp-content/uploads/image_5.png'); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that the whole slide-show can only point to one link, see the [FAQ](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/js-banner-rotate/faq/).

Comment: Hey Alix, looks like you're right; I'm going to try to add the link variable after each image but it probably won't work...